# node.js changing code is not reflecting in output

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I used to have a route with a post request named `/brands/createBrand`, no matter what changes I make to it, I cannot see the output. I tried hosting the whole thing onto the render.com service but saw no difference.

Things I tried to fix this,

- deleting the whole repo, making a new clone from the git
- changing the callback function names
- removing the route (as you can see, now the route doesn't exist. But when I make a post request to that I do not get an error)
- tried `npm start`, `nodemon start`, `node ./bin/www` assuming it would help but it did not.

Making changes to other functions or the routes gets updated but this one single route is stubborn. As I mentioned, even removing the route itself from the code isn't changing anything.

I tried adding several `console.log` statements but could not see any changes, nothing get's logged on to the console.

I created this project using the `npx express-generator`.

the code inside app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var headerRouter = require('./routes/headerFooter');
var brandsRouter = require('./routes/brands');
var dineRouter = require('./routes/dine');
var apiRouter = require('./routes/api');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors())

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/api/', apiRouter);
app.use('/header-footer', headerRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/brands', brandsRouter);
app.use('/dine', dineRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

the code inside routes/brands.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path'); 
var fs = require("fs");
var { index, listBrands, brandDetails, createBrand, updateBrand } = require('../controller/brands');
// import fetch from "node-fetch"
// var fetch = require("node-fetch")
/* GET home page. */


router.get('/', index);
router.get('/list', listBrands);
router.get('/:brandName', brandDetails);
router.post('/:brandName', updateBrand);
router.post('/newBrand', function (req, res, next){
    res.send({})
});

module.exports = router;
```

I still end up getting Status 200
[image]

Comment: Check the webserver configuration to see if it has a redirect.

Comment: that is what the route used to return earlier which I tried changing. Couldn't see the changes, tried a few things as mentioned, and ended up removing the route but I still get that response instead of getting an error saying route not found.

Comment: I finally realized what you were asking so I deleted my comment.

Comment: how do I check the web server configuration?

Comment: Depends on the webserver. But if this also happened when you uploaded the JS to a hosting service, that's probably not it.

Comment: I think this is happening because of the `/:brandName` route. It's filling in the `:brandName` placeholder with `createBrand`.

Comment: yes, on my local machine, I am not using any server other than using the mentioned commands to execute it. The other thing I tried is to deploy this on render.com which is giving me the same results. that is where I noticed that the changes are not being updated.

Comment: So it's calling `updateBrand('brandName')`

Comment: I thought that, but the console.log statements do not match up. there is a log on my terminal that says `createBrand` which I used to have earlier in the callback function for `/createBrand` which does not exist in `updateBrand();`

Comment: If you're still seeing console.log messages from the old code, you haven't correctly deployed the change. There's no way we can tell what you did wrong when trying to deploy.

Comment: okay changing the `/:brandName` to `/update/:brandName` worked. Probably that was the issue. but doesn't explain the console outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think this is happening because of the /:brandName route. It's filling in the :brandName placeholder with createBrand. –
> Barmar

As Barmar mentioned, changing the route name of post `/:brandName` to something else worked. seems like it did consider createBrand and newBrand under :brandName